# How to accept only https traffic and deny all http traffic using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, security, http, https

In a java web application, my goal is to accept only https requests and deny all http requests.

In the spring security config file, I'm using the requires-channel="https" attribute in the intercept-url tag, however this automatically redirects to https if the user requests http.

Example:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
```

If the client tries to hit the app via http, how can I respond with a 404 Not Found, and as a result do not automatically redirect to https?

Comment: Isn't that kind of inconvenient for the user?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should allow HTTP, but immediately do a redirect to the same URL but at HTTPS. You could do this centrally in Tomcat, or on a different system such as NginX
2. Use [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). This will tell the browser, in the future, to go directly to the HTTPS page even if the user enters HTTP.

Comment: What I currently have shown in the example already redirects to https automatically. We don't want this for security reasons as we are developing an OAUTH2 security token service platform and the client should know exactly it's requesting.